# Swift ForEach with non constant range View Refresh

Tags: swift, view, swiftui-foreach

I know it's a simple question, but I haven't found an answer. I want to understand the underlying concept.

I'm trying to update a ForEach with a non constant range, the closing parameter is a variable that is assigned to a button.

The variable is assigned with a @State so it's supposed to refresh the view. Somehow it's not working.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numberOfTimes = 5
    let timesPicker = [2,5,10,12,20]
    @State private var tableToPractice = 2
    enum answerState {
        case unanswered
        case wrong
        case right
    }
    func listRange(){
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    Form{
                        Section {
                            Picker("Tip percentage", selection: $numberOfTimes) {
                                ForEach(timesPicker, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0, format: .number)
                                }
                            }
                            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                        } header: {
                            Text("How many times do you want to practice?")
                        }
                        Section{
                            Stepper("Table to practice: \(tableToPractice.formatted())", value: $tableToPractice, in: 2...16 )
                        }
                            Button("Start Now", action: listRange).buttonStyle(.bordered)
                        

                        
                        List{
                            ForEach(0..<numberOfTimes){
                                Text("Dynamic row \($0)")
                            }
                        }
                    }.foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `tableToPractice` has to be used in the `body` somewhere (other than the stepper). If not there is no need to refresh. Watch Demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC21. What do you expect to refresh that isn't?

Comment: I'm trying to adjust the dynamic list length based on the number of times multiplyPractice is changed.

Comment: @BoPa I don't see where `multiplyPractice` is changed. You said it changes when tapping the button so perhaps you should include code for `listRange`?

Comment: @George I realized I made a glaring error with regards to the assignment. I had gotten ahead of myself with the variable creation. I fixed it, but the issue still persists.

Basically when the picker for how many times do you want to practice '''numberOfTimes''' changes, the number of lists doesn't change. That's what I'm trying to understand

Comment: When im using preview I get this message in the terminal:

ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, Text> count (10) != its initial count (5). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

How would I provide an explicit ID when it's a variable range? A tad confused.

Comment: @BoPa There is an initializer specifically for a constant range, such as `0 ..< 3`. However, because it is not constant, you need to specify the `id` (a different initializer). A simple way to fix this is using `id: \.self` so that each row is uniquely identified by the index (each element from `0 ..< numberOfTimes`). That may break animations though so you should `id` depending on what makes the data for that row **completely** unique. Identifying with the `\.self` key-path will be sufficient without animations.

Comment: @George so I should change it to this? List{
                            ForEach(selection: numberOfTimes, id: \.self){
                                Text("Dynamic row \($0)")
                            }
                        }

Comment: @BoPa Just add the `id` parameter to what you have in your question. `selection` is different

Comment: still does not work and I don't understand why.

Comment: @BoPa `ForEach(0 ..< numberOfTimes, id: \.self) { ... }` is valid. What's not working? It's hard for me to figure out the issue without a [mre].

Comment: @George I'm literally plugging in your example in the code that's up there (the minimal reproducible example) in Xcode and it gives me a systax error and doesn't give me more information lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the range is not identified. Lets make some rows

```
    struct Row: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
    }
```

Then set up an array of identifiable items

```
    @State private var numberOfTimes = 5
    @State private var rows = Array(repeating: Row(), count: 5)
```

Now you can have a responsive list

```
    List{
        ForEach(rows) { row in
            Text("Dynamic row")
        }
    }
```

Call the on change update to recreate the array

```
    .onChange(of: numberOfTimes) { newValue in
        rows = Array(repeating: Row(), count: newValue)
        numberOfTimes = newValue
    }
```

the onChange should be called on the Form.

This will make more sense when you have better view model data, see apple documentation for a more in depth example.

This is for lazy v stack, but the data model setup is what I'm thinking of

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grouping-data-with-lazy-stack-views

Comment: For some reason I had an error code that Xcode was missing library components when I added the code.

When I restarted it it worked. Thank you.

Adding id: \.self also worked after restarting it. Would you mind explaining what's the difference?

I'm still learning.

Comment: To my understanding SwiftUI just compares the views, so if the hashvalue isequal, the view is not updated. You can also set the hashvalue directly. How to maintain this om a good way is a complex question where i try to find Apple patterns if i can